# Solidity Identifier not found or not unique

Tags: solidity

when i type this code myUser memory user;  give redline like "Identifier not found or not unique."

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract User {

 struct MyUser {
    address publicKey;
    string userName;
 }

 MyUser[] public users;

 function createUser(
    string memory _userName
 ) public {

    myUser memory user;

    user.publicKey = msg.sender;
    user.userName = _userName;

    users.push(user);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a reference of MyUser struct but calling it as myUser..

Changing MyUser instead of myUser will fix the issue..

```
 function createUser( string memory _userName) public {
    MyUser memory user;
    user.publicKey = msg.sender;
    user.userName = _userName;
    users.push(user);
 }
```

Comment: hahhahaaaaha mb